# SSL certificate error with SAHI

Tags: proxy, ssl-certificate, sahi

I use SAHI for automated testing. Sahi has an internal proxy I use to interact with server application.
When I browse https websites, the proxy stores the sslcertificate. This certificate are self-signed and I have to import clicking on “Continue to this website (not recommended).”

It is boring but it but it works in many cases. Now I have to work with a hhtps site where this procedure doesn't work.
If i try to click on “Continue to this website (not recommended).”, nothing happen.
If I browse the site without proxy, I have no problems.

I use Win7, IE9.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Open Source version of Sahi you could try the latest release of https://github.com/headissue/Sahi 
since https://github.com/headissue/Sahi/releases/tag/v4.4.0-H7E it is possible to just click on the cert link on the startpage (*s*/dyn/Driver_initialized), then you never have to accept a certificate again.

I would appreciate if you try it out and feel free to contact me when you got any questions.

Comment: Thank you for your hint, but I forgot to specify I am working on Windows7. Can I use the release on win platform?

Comment: I guess not. We pretty much ignored Windows for now and hoped that someday a Windows user would contribute to the Github project to make sure it runs on Windows as well :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the reason of the problem, however I solved it just using Firefox.
With FireFox I can import the certificate just as usual, so I exported the certificate with FF than I importet it in IE and that's all.

Does any body know the reason of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:**
The website which you are trying to access may request resources from other domain other than the base domain(For base domain you have added the certificate while launching the URL)

**Solution:**
Open the developer tool goto network tab and search for any other domain and open the domain in a new tab, click "Proceed to website" (Chrome) or "I understand the risk" (firefox). Similarly do above steps for all the domains
Reload the page and check whether its displaying all the contents